# Last unique index for hover and delete action with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've build an image galary. From a database I load some images, with AJAX I add a new image to the collection.

After that 'add' I run this javascript to bind a hover event to the new image.

```
    $(".buildMedia").click(function() { 

     //Append with ajax a new image to the gallery
     $("#media-list").append("<li id=\"media&" + $("#addUpdateIdField").val() + "&" + "100" + ".jpg\"><a href=\"../images/redcont/" + $("#addUpdateIdField").val() + ".jpg\" class=\"hover\" ><img src=\"../images/redcont/" + $("#addUpdateIdField").val() + ".jpg\"/></a><button class=\"deleteMedia\">Verwijder</button></li>");

    // Bind hover to all `<li>` with the class hover    
    $('a.hover'+$("#addUpdateIdField").val()).hover(function(e){    
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="image" />')
      .css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX})
      .appendTo('body');
    }, function(){
       $('#largeImage').remove();
    });
    $('a.hover'+$("#addUpdateIdField").val()).mousemove(function(e){
       $('#largeImage').css({'top':e.pageY + offsetY,'left':e.pageX + offsetX});
    });
       $('a.hover$'+("#addUpdateIdField").val()).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       });
   });
   ......
```

On this way the hover event binds on the new image that I add, but also **double** to the existing images with all had a binding.

What can I do?

1. Generate an unique hoverclass-name. Maybe with a unique `<li>` index? But how can I received the last index integer?
2. Or are there other solutions?

Comment: Why don’t you simply add the hover effect on the <li> with the Id media&+inputfield.val()?

Comment: Yes, I had figured that out too. But when I add the same image (same image name) the event wil be double on the first. So I think maybe kan I use the index, thats always unique...

Comment: You should never have two elements with the same Id in the Dom. So you will have a problem in your code if you have two images with the same name. What you can do: add the actual timestamp in milliseconds to the Id